# is there way to check if window.location.replace is completed?

Tags: javascript

I am using window.location.replace(URL) to download file from mounted path on server.
I wanted to delete the file from server after downloading on local system using different API.
But I am not sure if file download is completed or not.
Is there a way to check if window.location.replace(URL) action is completed?

Comment: You can have a look at here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106377/detect-when-browser-receives-file-download . Maybe if that helps you at some extent.

Comment: It did not help me, since i am not using get/post request download file

Comment: What are you using then?

Comment: window.location.replace(URL), where url is a absolute path of file mounted on server. Using this, i can download file on local system